# My php script encodes (json) some text data to null

Tags: php, json

so I have a php file that has a function which returns an array encoded to jason with all the users from a database. If I'm not able to get the users because of any reason, it should be encoded something like:

```
sucesso = 0;
erro = 1;
msg_erro = "error message..."
```

Well, everything is fine except for the msg_erro, because the response is sent with this value null, even if there was an error ...

```
<?php    

    function getUsers() {    

        require_once 'connection.php';    
        mysql_select_db($con_database, $con) or die("erro mysql_select_db() -> users.php");     

        $users = array();    
        $resposta = array("sucesso" => 0, "erro" => 0);    

        $query = "SELECT * FROM utilizador WHERE cod_utilizador = 'x-3219'";    
        $result = mysql_query($query);    
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);    

        if($rows > 0) {    
            $resposta["sucesso"] = 1;    
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {    
                $users[] = array("cod" => $row["cod_utilizador"], 
                                 "password" => $row["password"],
                                 "nome" => $row["nome"],
                                 "rank" => $row["tipo_utilizador"]);    
            }    
            $resposta["utilizadores"] = $users;    
        } else {    
            $resposta["erro"] = 1;    
            $resposta["msg_erro"] = "Não existem utilizadores na base de dados!";    
        }    

        return json_encode($resposta);    
    }    

    /*    
    $fp = fopen('resultados.json', 'w');    
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($resposta));    
    fclose($fp);    
    */    

?>
```

So, this would get error, and it really does, except for the message like I said:

```
Array ( [sucesso] => 0 [erro] => 1 [msg_erro] => )
```

Why is msg_erro sent null ?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but have you tried to encode your string? I think the ã can block it and make it delete the string. But I'm not sure

Comment: @Kyu_ , yup, the problem is with ã, I'm trying to fix that with utf8_encode and iconv, but I'm still getting "NÃ£o" instead of "Não"

Comment: Another solution is to convert special chars. For example "ã" become "&Atilde;" But i'm not sure that the & will not break your json like the ã. And I can't try currently.

Comment: Thanks, it didn't break my json, it's correct now, but it has to be "&atilde;" and not "&Atilde;", because A is not capital letter.. What happens when I receive names with special chars from the database ? I can't fix them manually, is there any function that deals with this ? @Kyu_

Comment: The header was missing, that's it ! Thanks for the help @Kyu_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual culprit of resulting in empty strings is that the given `array` contains non-UTF-8 strings, while  [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/json_encode) *only* support UTF-8 encoding.

You can feed an arbitrary plain ASCII string in the error message to see whether it's an encoding problem.

```
    ....
    // error message block
    } else {    
        $resposta["erro"] = 1;    
        $resposta["msg_erro"] = "plain ASCII text";    
    }
```

If above code produces an intended result, [iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) or [mb_convert_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) can be helpful.

Converting an `array` to UTF-8 is explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16607515/760211 .

Comment: yup, this is the problem, I tried to use ut8_encode and iconv like I found in the link you provide me, and now I get the message, but it is still bad encoded: "NÃ£o existem utilizadores na base de dados!" ..

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I've just defined the header of the php file and then the data is delivered with no special chars, so we don't need to ut8_encode that data from the db.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score -1):

It is probabily because the data on you array is not UTF-8.

I fix using this function: `json_encode(recursiveUTF8($data));`

```
function &recursiveUTF8(&$array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
        unset($new_key);
        if (!mb_check_encoding($key, 'UTF-8')) {
            $new_key = utf8_encode($key);
            if (is_array($value)) {
                unset($array[$key]);
                $array[$new_key] = &$value;
            } elseif (is_object($value)) {
                unset($array->$key);
                $array->$new_key = &$value;
            }
            $key = $new_key;
        }
        if (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) {
            String::recursiveUTF8($value);
        } elseif (!mb_check_encoding($value, 'UTF-8')) {
            $value = utf8_encode($value);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: If you had read the entire discussion you'd know that this question was already answered more than two years ago...

Comment: I think that the solution I posted is more expansive. A friend of mine has tried the other solution and it has not solved his problem. And this question is the first one that is showed on Google.