# mysql json encode with äüß

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

I have got  a problem with json decode. After getting data form my mysql table I try to encode it to json but I get only "null"

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM plugins";
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
           $json_array = array();  
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
           {  
                $json_array[] = $row;  
           }  
           /*echo '<pre>';  
           print_r(json_encode($json_array));  
           echo '</pre>';*/  
           echo json_encode($json_array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're most likely not retrieving from your database in `UTF-8`. The best way of tackling that would probably be to run your queries in `UTF-8`, like this:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $connect);
```

Or you could convert your array to `UTF-8` as mentioned in the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16607515/4493079

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is mysql or mysqli correct? and there is a new problem Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /var/www/web29354858/html/connect/getjson.php on line 7